# Кто прав? Достаточно ли грамотны чиновники?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте. Объясните, пожалуйста, как правильно. Если пишут, например: надо документы подать до 5-го числа, значит ли это, что 5-е является последним днём подачи документов? Или это значит, что последним днём было 4-е число?

Comment: Нет, слова "включительно" не было. В Министерстве образования таких слов не знают.

Comment: Плохо, что не знают. Хотя они много чего не знают.  
Но я ничего больше не могу посоветовать. Кроме как не доводить до критической даты.

Comment: Ок. Спасибо. Теперь буду знать, что с Министерствами надо быть осторожнее.

Comment: Дык оно ж при Ливанове совсем до ручки дошло... 
Сплошной анекдот. Министерство культуры отдыхает.

Comment: Да, я заметила. Письмо от министра образования противоречит само себе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ничего не значит.

- ["до" и "по" | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/forum/spravka/112546/)
- http://apno.ru/content/view/258/39/

и проч.

Вопрос поднимался бессчетное число раз, поэтому сразу выводы.
Русский язык сам по себе не определяет значение предлога "до (такой-то даты)" как "до включительно" или "до исключая (последнюю дату)". Поэтому надо писать документы,  всегда оговаривая этот вопрос отдельно.
Если подобное не сделано, то в случае юридических затруднений решение чиновников (если оно не в пользу физического лица) всегда можно оспорить. Правда это отберет много сил и средств. Поэтому лучше просто подстраховаться и не откладывать на последний день.

Answer (score 2):

Если нет слова "включительно", то последним днём сдачи должно быть 4-е. Если я должен придти до 5 часов, то придя в 5:01 я опоздаю.

Comment: А если придете в 5:00?